# very confused about permissions in postgres

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have multiple databases and each of them have multiple schemas.

I have a set of apps that connect to these databases. Each app has it own user and, depending on their function, the apps can:

- read / write all schemas and tables of a specific db, set functions/notifications
- read only all schemas and tables of a specific db

The schemas and tables can be created at any time, so the permissions need to be set with ALTER DEFAULT.

My understanding is that the ALTER DEFAULT has to be done by the user that will create the future tables. Is that correct?

Since I can have scenarios where User 1 can RO db A, but RW db B, while User 2 can only RO db B, etc.. using roles doesn't seem to be of any help here.

So I'm a bit confused how to set that up.

Then comes the next complication:
I can assign permissions as either SELECT (RO), or SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE (RW), but:

- what about sequences? I don't want a RW user to be able to alter the sequences, but they need to be able to use them
- then how does it work with functions? the RW users need to be able to set/update their own functions

Any example of this setup would be greatly appreciated because going through the doc didn't help me much and most of the questions / answers on SO seems to be very similar yet never exactly the same, so it's quite confusing :)

---

Edit, following 'a_horse_with_no_name''s suggestion in the comments, I did this:

here is my init.sql:

```
CREATE DATABASE accounts;
CREATE DATABASE analysis;
CREATE DATABASE exchange;

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE exchange    TO capture, analyzer, sunny, viewer;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE analysis    TO analyzer, sunny, viewer;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE accounts    TO sunny;
```

then I log in as admin to db exchange and do:

```
GRANT pg_write_all_data TO capture;
GRANT pg_read_all_data  TO analyzer, sunny, viewer;
```

and I create a table called instruments there

then I log in as capture to to db exchange and do an insert, and I get:

> 42501: permission denied for table instruments

so using the capture user on the exchange db, I should have the pg_write_all_data property; why do I get the error?

It looks like I have to grant usage of instruments to capture.. which defeats the purpose of the pg_write_all_data. If I do the grant, then it works. So it looks like adding the role doesn't work.

Comment: With Postgres 14, there is a pre-defined role: `pg_read_all_data` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/predefined-roles.html but that would include read access to all database. But that could be circumvented by not granting CONNECT privilege to the "read all" user for the other database.

Comment: I read about the role but it didn’t cross my mind that I could prevent users to log in to other DBs! I’ll experiment with that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since your users shall have different permissions in different databases, define read-only and read-write roles for each database.

For example, `db1_ro` has read-only permissions in `db1`, and `db2_rw` has read-write permissions in `db2`. Then you can grant them both to a user, and the user will have different permissions in different databases.

Using a sequence typically means to call `nextval()`. So you should give that user the `USAGE` privilege. To use `setval()`, the user would need `UPDATE`. Nobody except the owner can `ALTER` an object anyway.

Functions cannot be set or updated, only executed, for which there is the `EXECUTE` privilege, which is granted to `PUBLIC` by default.

Comment: but how can I create these roles in a context where the schemas and tables are not defined yet? for example db1_ro in my case would be need to be: RO on all schemas and tables to be created by any other user on db1

Comment: You will have to limit the roles that can create tables and run `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` on each of them for each database.